# Python Encoding is Really Slowing Down My Application

Tags: python, encoding, runtime

I'm working on a pretty data intensive algorithm here, and speed is my top priority. Essentially it involves working with very large strings. Without getting into too much detail, it works in the blink of an eye without these lines of code:

```
html = unicode(strip_tags(html_source), errors='ignore')
html2 = unicode(strip_tags(html_source2), errors='ignore')
```

The problems that occur if I don't encode each string into unicode is that I get the dreadful:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5747: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there anything I could do to streamline this process? The little bits of data that aren't in the ascii range are not too important to me. Is there anyway I could just ignore the errors all together without encoding the whole string?

Thank you very much! (I am currently using python2.7.3)

Comment: You could use `your_string.decode('ascii', 'ignore')` and strip out all non-ascii characters.

Comment: Wow. I feel... Not as smart as I did 15 seconds ago. Thank you very much! Feel free to post that answer and I'll check her off if you like.

Comment: Does it actually improve performance?

Comment: Yes it does, but I still get the ascii error sometimes... I'll have to sort that out. For example, if I use the urllib2 to produce the source code of facebook.com, and then try to strip that of html tags I get the ascii error. Even if I encode or decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip out all non-ASCII characters with `.decode()`:

```
your_string.decode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```